# Bootstrap Multi Nav Bars

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have to build a responsive dual bar header in Bootstrap - basically I have two navs - as follows - the first nav is a sub nav but due to the design it is in smaller case above the lead nav - my issue is that I want both to collapse and open with the mobile button - but I need the orders to be reversed - so that main nav (2nd list - beginning with home) comes first - is this possible simply - or does it require a jquery script?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-expanded">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBr">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                <img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Motor Depot Logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Nav Bar One-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#careers">Careers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#news">News</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#chat">Live Chat</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#phone">Phone</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        <!-- Nav Bar Two-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBr">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#showrooms">Showrooms</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#search">Search</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#serviceMot">Service &amp; MOT</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#smartDrive">SmartDrive</a>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#value">Value Your Car</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Offers</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>


        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Wait, so you have 1 stacked above 2 in desktop view, but in mobile you want 2 to stack above 1?

Comment: yep - seeing the design would make more sense - the sub nav is smaller top right - main nav beneath - but it doesnt make sense in that stacked order on mobile -I'm thinking the only way to solve the scenario is to stack it mobile and absolutely position the sub nav above on desktop?

Comment: I've never tried this before, but what if you wrap each nav in a col-12? With Bootstrap you can swap column order.

Answer (score 0):

Add both of your `.nav` elements into the collapsible menu element in the order you want them to appear when the menu is not collapsed.

Then use the `show.bs.collpase` event to change the `display` property of your collapsible menu to `flex` and use the `order` property on the first `.nav` element to come after the second `.nav` element.

Here is an example, sure you will get the idea.

```js
$('#navBr').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).css({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap'
  });
  $(this).find('.nav:first').css({
    order: 2,
  });
});
// Make sure to hide the #navBr after it has been closed
// and reset the display property.
$('#navBr').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  $(this).css({
    display: 'none',
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-expanded">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navBr">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Motor Depot Logo" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navBr">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#careers">Careers</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#chat">Live Chat</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#phone">Phone</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#showrooms">Showrooms</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#search">Search</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#serviceMot">Service &amp; MOT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#smartDrive">SmartDrive</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#value">Value Your Car</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Offers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```